# Log4j2 in a Unix environment

Tags: java, unix, classpath, log4j2

I have made a project in which I am creating logs with log4j2.xml. My configuration file works perfectly when I am running it in the eclipse of my windows system. Here is the configuration file which I have used to create the log files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/home/apps/ora_fin/IGL75D/Disco/splunk/log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile fileName="${log-path}/SplunkOADC.log" filePattern="${log-path}/SplunkOADC-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" name="info-log">
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>

        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile fileName="${log-path}/SplunkOADC-trace.log" filePattern="${log-path}/SplunkOADC-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" name="trace-log">

            <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>

            <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
             <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
             <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
             <ThresholdFilter level="FATAL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>

            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>

                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger level="all" name="com.aviva.uk.gi.NUProcessOSBReportDataParserPkg">
            <AppenderRef ref="info-log"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="trace-log"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration file I have put under the src folder in my project and is picked up without any issues. However I need to deploy the application in the Unix environment, where should I put the configuration file in unix environment so that it is picked up by the java class to log ??

Thanks!

Comment: There's webpage with THE answer: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Yes I have read the configuration in the documentation. What I need to know is that if I can load the configuration file in my java class using XMLConfiguration ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a jvm argument always

```
-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}
```

This should work irrespective of the environment you deploy in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where should I add this argument ?

Comment: Its a jvm argument. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html

Comment: I am adding the vm argument through my eclipse. In the arguments tab in run configurations. I am giving the full path to the log4j2.xml but when i run the project it gives me error. 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Users\460681\Desktop\Splunk-LocalVersion\NUProcessOSBReportDataParser_LocalSystem\src\com\aviva\uk\gi\NUProcessOSBReportDataParserPkg\log4j2.xml

Comment: Also I dont want it on a server level, I want the configuration file only for my project, but there are a lot of java projects deployed in the server. if I set it as a JVM argument it becomes open to all those projects as well.

Comment: I guess you deploy in some App server (JBoss, Glassfish...). Then just  pass file path to your project's log4j2 config file via application-specific property and load file from there.

Comment: I have deployed my application in a weblogic server. There are other java applications deployed on that server too. How do I then make sure that log4j2.xml is specific to just my application!

Comment: If the configuration file is supposed to be specific to one web application and you do have other web applications deployed on the same jvm instance then JNDI is another way of configuring. If not adding it to the WEB-INF/classes/ directory is an another option.

Comment: But I have a java application which takes messages from an MDB listener. I can't deploy it as a web application. And currently I use my configuration file by keeping it in the class path i.e. src/log4j2.xml and it is getting picked up. But when I deploy the application in weblogic server it stops working.

Comment: How do I configure using JNDI ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to just add the config file to the classpath of your application.

For a web app that means putting it in `WEB-INF/classes/`.

Alternatively you can use the system property suggested in the other answer.

Comment: But I have a java application which takes messages from an MDB listener. I can't deploy it as a web application. And currently I use my configuration file by keeping it in the class path i.e. src/log4j2.xml and it is getting picked up. But when I deploy the application in weblogic server it stops working